# R get_map returns map correctly, but filename argument does not work?

Tags: r, web-mapping, export, png, ggmap

In R library `ggmap` there is a function `get_map` which saves a file (or at least have saved files automatically two or three years ago). Now `get_map` is not saving anymore, although the parameter `filename` gives no warning, no error.

```
m <- get_map(c(lon0,lat0,lon9,lat9),maptype="satellite",filename='map1.png',messag=T)
```

Is `get_map` still expected to create a PNG file?

Comment: What's up? Is anybody able to save the map as png?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
library(ggmap)
png('map1.png')
ggmap(get_map(c(10, 20, 30, 40), maptype = "satellite"))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I can plot it, my question is why the "filename" parameter is not being used anymore, like it used to.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get `filename` to work using `ggmap` version 2.6.1 from August, 2016.

In one of my code attempts I got the following error message:

> In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>     cannot open URL 'http:// ...'

Then, searching this error in Google returned issue 142 in [ggmap GitHub](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/142) which was marked both as 'bug' and 'feature-request'. The problem seems to be related requesting maps using `http` instead of former `https`.

Comment: But this seems to be an internal error, nothing we could do about it?

Comment: @Rodrigo, you can try to modify the source code/function to make it work; but it would be simpler if the package's authors fixed it. Apparently, `ggmap` has not been updated in the last 2 years. My answer was based on your comment [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233158/r-get-map-returns-map-correctly-but-filename-argument-does-not-work/284565?noredirect=1#comment435727_273398) in which you were trying to understand what happened. So, probably a bug.